# Stably causal spacetimes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity

Consider a stably causal Lorentzian spacetime $(\mathcal{M},g)$, so that a non-zero timelike vector field $t^a$ exists such that

$$
\tilde{g}_{ab}=g_{ab}-t_a t_b
$$

and $(\mathcal{M},\tilde{g})$ has no closed timelike curves.

How do we show that $\tilde{g}$ also has Lorentz signature?

Comment: Normalize $t$ wrt $\tilde g$ and extend it to an orthonormal frame (ONF) by using $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, where $e_i$ are $g$-spacelike. Then see that this gives an ONF for $\tilde g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Clemens. Are you suggesting that the $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are a spatial ONF for $g$? Or are you suggesting that the $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ can be chosen to be the spatial ONF for $\tilde{g}$ and remain spacelike for $g$.

Comment: I have not worked it out in detail but I think $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ can be chosen to be spacelike for $\tilde g$, then you do not care anymore about $g$. So forget that part of my previous comment.